# MySQL outer join three tables

Tags: mysql, join, multiple-tables

I have trouble doing a join on three tables. I have these tables:

```
table teams:

id_team | team_name
--------+-----------
      1 | Alpha
      2 | Beta 
      3 | Charlie
--------+----------


table persons

id_person | name 
----------+------- 
        1 | Homer
        2 | Ned
        3 | Moe
----------+-------- 


table teams_has_persons

id_team | id_person | is_leader
--------+-----------+-----------
      1 |         1 |       0
      1 |         2 |       1 
      2 |         3 |       0
--------+-----------+-----------
```

A team may or may not contain persons.
A team may or may not have a leader, altough it has persons.
A team can only have one leader.

I want to list all teams with their leaders. 
If a team has no leader, a null (or anything else) should be displayed instead of the leader's name.
If a team is not present in the table teams_has_persons, it should be 
displayed as a team with no leader.

Desired output:

```
id_team | team_name | leader
--------+-----------+-----------
      1 | alpha     |  Ned
      2 | beta      |  <null>
      3 | charlie   |  <null>
--------+-----------+-----------
```

I have managed to build this query:

```
SELECT 
    a.id_team,
    a.team_name, 
    b.id_person, 
    b.is_leader, 
    c.name 

FROM 
    teams as a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (teams_has_persons as b INNER JOIN persons as c ON b.id_person = c.id_person ) ON (a.id_team = b.id_team)
```

which displays the list of teams with their associated persons but it not what I want.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/046668/1/0

Thank you all for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment...
do you need something like this?
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/046668/9

```
SELECT 
    a.id_team,
    a.team_name, 
    b.id_person, 
    b.is_leader, 
    c.name 

FROM 
    teams as a

    LEFT OUTER JOIN (teams_has_persons as b 
                     INNER JOIN persons as c ON b.id_person = c.id_person ) 
                     ON (a.id_team = b.id_team AND b.is_leader = 1)
```